# JPA query results in No Identifier

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA query in spring , My subclass extends Baseclass whic contains an **Id** only and My subclass has all the variavles that is used by the JPA query given below:

Base Class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "partcost")   
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Pg6p0012_01PartCostBaseQueryModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    String part_no;
}
```

Subclass :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partcost")   
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Pg6p0012_01PartCost1QueryModel extends Pg6p0012_01PartCostBaseQueryModel implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String stock_take_cost ;
private String cost_type ;
}
```

when I am hiting below JPA Query :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface Pg6p0012_01PartcostRepository extends JpaRepository<Pg6p0012_01PartCostBaseQueryModel, String>  {

@Query(value = "SELECT stock_take_cost,cost_type FROM partcost where part_no = :p_part_no", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Pg6p0012_01PartCost1QueryModel>getPartcost1Result(@Param("p_part_no") String p_part_no);
}
```

**its throwing Error:** No such column name
which is clear because query is returning only one column but Model has two columns .

How to tackle this ? please suggest.

Comment: User uses a "native query" (SQL) when JPQL would be perfectly good for that situation.

Comment: @Neil Stockton : Its an old project & I am not supposed to change the structre

Comment: Try replacing your `:p_part_no` with `?1` and remove the `@Param` annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You make part_no transient . It means that it is not persisted in the database.Therefore you are getting  no such column name error. Remove @Transient from the base class which is above the part_no.

And also annotate your base class with

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

Hibernate supports the three basic inheritance mapping strategies:

```
table per class hierarchy
table per subclass
table per concrete class
```

Comment: I tried by removing @Transient as well but still the error persists as model class has two fields but query is fetching only one column so, mapping is creating this error

Comment: I think the table "table_name" is not created in your database . Please check it.  And also  use one of the three types table per class hierarchy,table per subclass,table per concrete class because hibernate supports the three basic inheritance mapping strategies

Comment: table_name is dummy field in actual its something else which is present in the table

Comment: Ok update your real code Entity base class sub class repository service all. Then i will check .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131866/discussion-between-surace-and-shashi-ranjan).

Comment: only put @Inheritance to your base class not in child class

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for helping me out but now I have omited Native query. Thank you very much Surace.

Comment: Its okay. please update the solution what you have got .

Comment: Now iam using JPA inbuilt methods for searching... finBy(...).